# Getting rows according to last 24 hour shares mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am working on some kind of social message posting application. In that, I need to get the data trending data for past 24 hours. I have 3 tables - messages, users, shares

message - message_id, contents, user_id, created_at

users - user_id, email, and other data

shares - message_id, user_id, created_at

Now, what I am looking to fetch is message details, along with its total number of shares. And I want to sort those messages according to the highest shares over past 24 hours, which gives me viral messages.

I tried, it might be invalid try :

```
SELECT msg.`message_id`, msg.`user_id`, COUNT(share.user_id) share_count
msg.created_at, category FROM 
(select * from message_shares ms where created_at>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) trending,
 `messages` msg
left join message_shares share ON share.message_id = msg.message_id 
GROUP by msg.message_id order by msg.id desc
```

It is giving me invalid share_count also it is not giving valid results and messages. and it doesn't have the sorting of messages according to last 24 hrs share count.

I don't have much-advanced knowledge of MySQL queries. So please provide me approach or query to find those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```sql
SELECT messages.message_id, messages.user_id, messages.created_at, 
COUNT(*) AS share_count 
FROM messages
INNER JOIN shares ON messages.message_id = shares.message_id
WHERE shares.created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
GROUP BY shares.message_id
ORDER BY share_count DESC;
```

The intuitive explanation is, firstly, selecting the rows from `messages` joined with the rows from `share`, filtered with the condition that `created_at` of `share` is within a 24-hour interval. As a result of the join, there are as many rows with the same message as the number of shares this message has. Then you can group by `message_id` of `share`, so every message has a "group of its shares" and you can get the size of each group by adding the `COUNT(*)` column, which now works group-wise. Then you sort the rows by `share_count` and get the projection of the query with the fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

This formulation should avoid the "inflate-deflate" performance hit caused by "join...group by":

```
SELECT  messages.message_id, messages.user_id, messages.created_at,
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  shares  ON messages.message_id = message_id
            WHERE  created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
    ) AS share_count
    FROM  messages
    ORDER BY  share_count DESC;
```

Also, have on `shares`:

```
INDEX(message_id, created_at)
```

If you need further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved.

Comment: It's not working. It is returning the same 'share_count' for every row.